# Keep current file type/extension in Notepad++ "Save As..." dialog

Tags: notepad++

If I have a file type open that Notepad++ "knows" about-- that is, the file type appears in the file type dropdown menu in the "Save As..." dialog box-- the file type is maintained after a "Save As..." or a "Save a Copy As..." action.

However, no extension is provided when NP doesn't know about the file type I am working with, and I end up having to manually add the extension every time.

How can this problem be addressed? Is there a way to add a file extension to the file types NP++ "knows" about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no need

The SaveAs window *will* default to showing `.txt` in the file type drop-down, but if a type is given as part of the filename, it will use that instead.

For example, if you create a new file and name it `newfile.zzz`, open it with Np++ and then choose `SaveAs...` it will appear as:

```
File name:          newfile.zzz
Save as type:       Normal text file (*.txt)
```

However, if you just click the `Save` button at this point, the file will be saved as just `newfile.zzz` and not `newfile.zzz.txt`

### If you don't want .txt appearing in the type

In `Settings`->`Preferences`->`Default Directory` tick *"Use new style save dialog"* and it will default to showing `all types (*.*)` when you go to save.

### Adding a language

If the language exists as one that notepad knows about, but with a unique file extension, then you can add that extension in the style configurator.

`Settings`->`Style Configurator`->`Language`

Select your language and add your extension at the bottom, in the `User ext` box.

If Notepad++ doesn't know about your language, then you can add one:

`Language`->`Define your language`

The minimum amount you need to do is `Save As`, set your language name, then set the file extension you want.

This may help, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I'll add a screenshot or .gif of this in action when I get home, if that will help.

Comment: This does not work this way for me in v7.5.9. Follow these steps: 1. create a new file (Ctl+N) 2. Save as "foo.zzz" 3. Save as "bar" (hit enter), the file extension is removed.

Comment: Follow up: the solution is your last suggestion-- add a new language. You have to add the user defined language AND associate its file extension. THEN it will all work as wanted. THANKS!